# Fancybox (модальное окно) не работает со слайдером (

Tags: jquery

Сделала вот эту страницу: http://kerrigan.su/slider2/

Не работает модальное окно внизу.

В предыдущей версии http://kerrigan.su/slider/ модальное окно отлично работает. Но там я никак не смогла в кнопки слайдера вывести текст, тут спрашивала, никто не смог помочь, пришлось использовать другой слайдер, переписала все заново, но теперь не работает модальное окно.

Что мне сделать, чтобы http://kerrigan.su/slider2/ оно заработало ?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'on' (index):204
3
Uncaught TypeError: Object undefined has no method 'addClass' jquery.jshowoff.min.js:15
2
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'prop' jquery.fancybox.js:285
4
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'prop'

Answer (score 1):

У вас в заголовке страницы подключается старая версия jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

подключите более новую и все должно заработать

Comment: Спасибо огромное !!! Вы меня спасли ! Более новая версия jquery помогла ) Отдаю вам свою единственную единичку за это ! :***